# Swift: Cuando uso dismiss la pantalla se congela

Tags: swift

Tengo una pantalla que cuando se ingresa, en automático se reproduce un video y después este desaparece, pero cuando lo hace el viewcontroller debajo parece quedarse congelado, no responde a las pulsaciones, ademas de mostrar el siguiente mensaje en la salida:

```
[Assert] Trying to present the presentation controller while transitioning already. (<AVPresentationController: 0x12bd254f0>)
```

Variable del objeto de video:

```
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
```

Método que construye y reproduce el video:

```
private func playVideo() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "intro", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("intro.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerController.player?.currentItem)
        
    self.present(playerController, animated: false) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Se puede notar la presencia de un observador para ejecutar una funcion cuando este termina su reproducción.

La función que se ejecuta:

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    self.playerController.dismiss(animated: false)
}
```

he intentado algo como para darle tiempo, por el mensaje que recibo:

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.9) {
        self.playerController.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
}
```

pero no logro que cambie ese comportamiento.

Comment: Cómo haces el llamado a `playVideo()`?

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        playVideo()
}`
Me diste la idea de probar en los otras funciones de inicio, lo cambie a `override func viewDidLoad() {}`y eso lo soluciono